# Deleting a node in Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, c++17, binary-search-tree

I made a function to delete a node from BST. I was wondering if the two recursive codes do the same thing or not

```
BstNode* temp = new BstNode();
temp = root;
delete(root);
return temp->left;
```

```
return root->left;
```

I know that the first one deletes root from the heap memory but it adds temp to the memory so is it same as the second code?

Comment: No. First code is leaking memory and dereferencing freed memory. Such dangerous things are not done (at least not shown) in the second code.

Comment: `temp = root;delete(root)` -- Unless you are totally not familiar with pointers, this is obviously wrong.

Comment: @MikeCAT so we should delete temp instead to free it from the heap memory?  like, root=root->left; delete(temp)?

Comment: Before asking further questions, do you understand *why* the code pointed out is bad?  How to fix the code is secondary, the primary focus should be on understanding why that code even exists.

Comment: Why are you creating new node for deleting a node?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i guess because i allocated the memory before deleting so its never deleted actually

Comment: @MikeCAT because its a recursive function so i have to return something and can't delete the node before returning without using another node

Comment: @sudhanshu  You are pointing to the same location, and you're calling `delete` on that location.  I think the issue is that you were mislead into believing that the difference in the pointer name means different pointer values.  No.  So my suspicions were accurate -- you are not familiar with pointer usage.

Comment: i dont understand how any of this delets a node from a tree. `return root->left` merely returns the `left` of `root`.

Comment: Is another node really required? Isn't just *a pointer to* a node enough?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes i'm new to pointers. Couldn't find problems to practice anywhere.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 its a recursive function so the previous pointer just ignores the value in root and points to the next node. so its still in memory but not in bst

Comment: @MikeCAT the youtuber where i learned from used another node, so i thought its the most efficient way

Comment: there is no recusion in the snippets you posted

Comment: @sudhanshu -- You should be focusing on the *value* the pointer holds, not the name of the pointer.  The call to `delete` works on pointer *values*.  That's why those two lines of code pointed out earlier in the comments made absolutely no sense.  The two pointers, `temp` and `root` hold the same *value* when you called `delete`, thus you wiped both of them out in a single `delete`..

Comment: colloquially we say "delete the pointer" but pedantically it would be more correct to say "delete the object that the pointer points to"

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it has to be said clear: This code makes no sense whatsoever.

> ```
> BstNode* temp = new BstNode();   // (1)
> temp = root;                     // (2)
> delete(root);                    // (3)
> return temp->left;               // (4)
> ```

`(1)` dynamically allocates a `BstNode`. After assigning `root` to `temp` in `(2)` the memory allocated in `(1)` is leaked. You lost any reference to it.

Then `(3)` deletes `root` but `temp` points to the same, it has the same value as `root` because of the assignment in `(2)`. Hence `(4)` is undefined behavior due to dereferencing a dangling pointer.

This code is no good.

On the other hand this:

```
return root->left;
```

dereferences `root` and returns its `left` member. If `root` is a valid pointer this code is not causing same desaster as the first.

Comment: @sudhanshu what do you mean? After `delete root;` the node pointed to by `root` does not exist anymore.

Comment: @sudhanshu and because `temp` does point to the same node (due to `temp = root`), after `delete root;` all nodes are gone, at least the ones present in that code

Comment: oh okay now I get the idea of whats going on, I thought of them as variables

Comment: @sudhanshu they are variables. I am not sure what your misunderstanding is, but you should not confuse the pointer and the object it points to. Pointers can be confusing but actually they are quite primitive and simple: Pointers point somewhere. Thats about all they do.